# Make workbox show workflows outside of sitecore/system/workflows

Tags: sitecore

Sitecore's workbox seems to only be able to show items that are in workflows in sitecore/system/workflows. Is there a way to make it show workflows in other parts of the tree? I have been able to solve several issues with moving a workflow out of that location but this one is the current sticking point.

Our site is divided into several sections for different clients (in the "customers" sense of the word). The clients each need their own workflows and we would like them to be able to navigate to the workflows without having to get out of the content portion of the tree and into the system portion. Ideally we would also like to move as much of each client's custom stuff, e.g. layouts, renderings, etc, as we can into the content area so that we or they can publish that one node and subitems and have everything related to that client go live, like what I am guessing most people do with the "publish site" function.

Comment: Interesting... why would you move a workflow out of there?

Comment: I edited to explain why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be curious what you've done so far to alleviate this. Using reflector, I searched for the Workflow root item's GUID, `{05592656-56D7-4D85-AACF-30919EE494F9}`. It is stored in `Sitecore.ItemIDs.WorkflowRoot`, which is used in turn by `Sitecore.Workflows.Simple.WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflows()`. This method is called by, among other places, `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm`. However, it is accessed through `Context.ContentDatabase.WorkflowProvider`, which is a configuration element located at `/sitecore/databases/database/workflowProvider`.

Long story short, if you haven't already, you should try implementing your own `IWorkflowProvider` that extends `Sitecore.Workflows.Simple.WorkflowProvider` and configure it in your Web.config. Override `GetWorkflows()` to find workflows from the location you're looking for. Use a tool like reflector or ILSpy to see what this method does currently, and make the necessary changes.

Please report back (blog it if you can!). This is not an area of Sitecore that I think many people usually extend/enhance.

Comment: Excellent answer! The default workflowprovider is easy to subclass and override and makes extending the simple workflow very straightforward.